# I am using Google Maps API and I Can't Update Circle Radius Through Input Box and Button

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am trying to update the radius of my circle through input box and button. I have the following code but It won't work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<apex:page controller="GeoLocatorController" sidebar="false" showheader="false">

<head>


<style type="text/css">

html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map-canvas { width:100%;height:80%; }
.controls    

</style>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBJkHXEVXBSLY7ExRcxoDxXzRYLJHg7qfI"></script>


<script>

var circle;


function initialize() {

//Setting default center of the system
var mapCenter = {
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapCenter);

//Get User's Geolocation and Set as the Center of the System
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

        userLat = position.coords.latitude;
        userLng = position.coords.longitude;

        userLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.setCenter(userLoc);


//User Marker's Image    
var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';


//Create Marker for the User's Location     
var centerLoc = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : userLoc,
    map : map,

    title : 'Your Position!',
    draggable : true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });


//Create Circle and Bind it to User's Location  
    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    radius: 500,    // 10 miles in metres
    fillColor: '#AA0000'
    });
    circle.bindTo('center', centerLoc, 'position'); 
    });

//Updating the value from the input box into Circle Radius        
function updateRadius(){
var rad = document.getElementById("value_rad").value;
circle.setRadius(parseFloat(rad));
}

}


loadHotels();


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
console.log()


//Load Records from Cloud    
function loadHotels() {

Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.GeoLocatorController.findAll}',

function(result, event){

if (event.status) {
    for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
        var id = result[i].Id;
        var name = result[i].Name;
        var lat = result[i].Location__Latitude__s;
        var lng = result[i].Location__Longitude__s;
        addMarker(id, name, lat, lng);
    }
} else {
     alert(event.message);
    }
},
 {escape: true}
);       
}



//Create Markers for the Records from the Cloud        
function addMarker(id, name, lat, lng) {

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        title: name
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
    window.top.location = '/' + id;
});

}



</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:80%;"/>


<input id="value_rad" placeholder="Enter Search Area Radius (km)" />
<input id="radius" type="button" value="Search" onclick="updateRadius()"/>


</body>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position of `updateRadius` method is incorrect. It must be outside of `initialize` method and after the `addMarker` function.

Example:

```
<script>

var circle;


//.... to much code here except "updateRadius"



//Create Markers for the Records from the Cloud        
function addMarker(id, name, lat, lng) {

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        //... some more stuff
             }); 
}

// Updating the value from the input box into Circle Radius        
function updateRadius(){
   var rad = document.getElementById("value_rad").value;
   circle.setRadius(parseFloat(rad));
}


</script>
```